# Обрезка текста в php

Tags: php, html

Всем привет есть запрос в БД.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY $sorting $qury_start_num",$link);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {  
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    do
    { 
                echo'

          <p class="elliosis">'.$row["description"].'</p>

              ';}while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));  }
```

Как сделать так чтобы текст строки description выводилась с ограничением? 
Если 1000 символов то 100 и в конце добавлялась ...

Comment: SELECT IF( CHAR_LENGTH( description) >1000, CONCAT( LEFT( description, 100) ,  '...' ) , description) 
FROM  news 
ORDER BY $sorting $qury_start_num

Answer (score 1):

```
// Обрезать строку
function cropStr($str, $length = 300, $sign = ' &hellip;') {
    $str = trim($str);
    $result = mb_substr($str, 0, $length, 'UTF-8');
    if ($length < mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8')) {
        $result = rtrim($result, '!,.-');
        $result = $result . $sign;
    }
    return $result;
}

$str = 'Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянный количественный рост';
echo cropStr($str, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [mb-strimwidth](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strimwidth.php)

```
<p class="elliosis">'.mb_strimwidth($row["description"], 0, 1000, '&hellip;').'</p>
```

Обратите внимание, что $width символов в результате будет уже с учетом заполнения

Пример:

```
print mb_strimwidth('Hello, stackoverflow на русском!', 0, 20 + strlen('&hellip;'), '&hellip;');
```

Результат:

```
Hello, stackoverflow…
```

Answer (score 0):

Как уже говорилось в одном из ответов, можно использовать штатные средства PHP:

```
$text = 'PHP — скриптовый язык программирования общего назначения, активно применяемый для разработки веб-приложений. Используйте эту метку, если у Вас возникли вопросы по применению данного языка или о самом языке';

echo mb_strimwidth($text, 0, 70, " ...");
// PHP — скриптовый язык программирования общего назначения, активно приме ...
```

Но если нужно в результате усечения строки сохранять целостность слов, то скорее всего придётся писать нечто вроде этого:

```
/**
 * Сокращение текста
 * 
 * @param string  $text   - Текст для обработки
 * @param string  $link   - Ссылка на оригинал
 * @param integer $length - Длина сокращённого текста
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function reduction($text, $link = '?', $length = 75)
{
    if (mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8') > $length) {
        $substr = mb_substr($text, 0, $length, 'UTF-8');

        $text = strpos($substr, ' ') !== false 
            ? preg_replace('~(\s)?(?(1)\S+$|\s$)~', '', $substr) 
            : strstr($text, ' ', true);

        $text .= " ... <a href='$link'><span style='color:red;'>&raquo;&raquo;</span></a>";
    }

    return $text;
}


$text = 'PHP — скриптовый язык программирования общего назначения, активно применяемый для разработки веб-приложений. Используйте эту метку, если у Вас возникли вопросы по применению данного языка или о самом языке';

echo reduction($text);
// PHP — скриптовый язык программирования общего назначения, активно ... »»
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo strip_tags(mb_substr($row["description"], 0, 100)) . "...";
```

> **strip_tags** - функция пытается возвратить строку, из которой удалены все NULL-байты, HTML- и PHP-теги. Для удаления тегов используется тот же автомат, что и в функции fgetss().
>   http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php
>
> **mb_substr** - mb_substr() возвращает часть строки str, заданную параметрами start и length.
>   http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php